# create virtuemart view in database

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to create a view in myphp , I am not a coder I am studying ,
could somebody help me ?
This is my query

```
CREATE VIEW export AS SELECT * FROM
apef1_virtuemart_orders, apef1_virtuemart_order_items, apef1_virtuemart_order_userinfos
WHERE apef1_virtuemart_orders.virtuemart_order_id = apef1_virtuemart_order_items.virtuemart_order_id 
AND apef1_virtuemart_orders.virtuemart_order_id = apef1_virtuemart_order_userinfos.virtuemart_order_id
```

but I get this error

## 1060 - Duplicate column name 'virtuemart_order_id'

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to your `select * from apef1_virtuemart_orders, apef1_virtuemart_order_items, apef1_virtuemart_order_userinfos`. The `virtuemart_order_id` column is present in more than 1 table.

If you have name conflict between tables, you have to use aliases to ensure view is created correctly.

See this query :

```
CREATE VIEW export AS 
    SELECT 
    avo.*, 
    avoi.order_item_sku,
    avoi.order_item_name,
    avoi.product_quantity,
    avoi.product_item_price,
    avoi.product_priceWithoutTax,
    avoi.product_tax,
    avoi.product_basePriceWithTax,
    avoi.product_discountedPriceWithoutTax,
    avoi.product_final_price,
    avoi.product_subtotal_discount,
    avoi.product_subtotal_with_tax,
    avoi.order_item_currency,
    avoi.order_status AS order_status_2,
    avoi.product_attribute,
    avoi.delivery_date AS delivery_date_2,
    avoi.created_on AS created_on_2,
    avoi.created_by AS created_by_2,
    avoi.modified_on AS modified_on_2,
    avoi.modified_by AS modified_by_2,
    avoi.locked_on AS locked_on_2,
    avoi.locked_by AS locked_by_2,
    avou.virtuemart_userinfo_id,
    avou.virtuemart_user_id,
    avou.address_type,
    avou.address_type_name,
    avou.name,
    avou.company,
    avou.title,
    avou.last_name,
    avou.first_name,
    avou.middle_name,
    avou.phone_1,
    avou.phone_2,
    avou.fax,
    avou.address_1,
    avou.address_2,
    avou.city,
    avou.virtuemart_state_id,
    avou.virtuemart_country_id,
    avou.zip,
    avou.agreed,
    avou.tos,
    avou.customer_note,
    avou.created_on AS created_on_3,
    avou.created_by AS created_by_3,
    avou.modified_on AS modified_on_3,
    avou.modified_by AS modified_by_3,
    avou.locked_on AS locked_on_3,
    avou.locked_by AS locked_by_3
    FROM
        apef1_virtuemart_orders avo, 
        apef1_virtuemart_order_items avoi, 
        apef1_virtuemart_order_userinfos avou
    WHERE avo.virtuemart_order_id = avoi.virtuemart_order_id 
    AND avo.virtuemart_order_id = avou.virtuemart_order_id
```

As you can see, i used aliases for the columns `created_on`, `created_by` etc because these names are the same for your 3 tables. Feel free to modify the query by adjusting the names to fit your needs.

Comment: i undertood now . many many thanks for your support . have a nice day God bless you

Comment: Glad to help you ;-) Could you please mark question as solved ?

Comment: Guillaume SOLVED THE PROBLEM